# Get selected values from multiple dynamically generated Mat Selection Lists in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am generating and populating multiple `<mat-selection-list>`s, the number of which is dynamic and based on user input. I need to collect the selected values from those lists upon submission, but I don't know how to uniquely identify the lists.

Each instance of user input results in *two* `<mat-selection-lists>`s, so I need to not only identify which variety of the two list but also which instance of user input populated the list.

The lists are currently generated in an *ngFor loop and I am tracking the index value of each list, so if I could attach that index value to something like a template reference variable for each list variety I would be set.

A potential solution would look something like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let customer of customersAry; let x=index">
  <!-- Here is where I would create a dynamic variable name
       to be referenced in the typescript file -->
  <mat-selection-list #'details'+k>
    <mat-list-option>Name</mat-list-option>
    <mat-list-option>Email</mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

where I create some type of dynamic variable attached to the `<mat-selection-list>` tag.

I've tried using template reference variables as seen here as well as [(ngModel)] but can't find a solution that solves my problem.

Comment: Are you binding any of the values? You could use template-driven (the `[(ngModel)]` or reactive form techniques to bind the values to set of arrays and then you would have the values. Can you also post what the code looked like with `[(ngModell)]`?

Comment: I did a stackblitz with an `[(ngModel)]` solution here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aodhky (It doesn't use material design, but it should basically work the same ... just look nicer. :-) ). Note that as you select the options in the drop downs, the data on the bottom automatically changes because it is bound to the `products` array values.

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks so much for your help. I'm sorry but the input device I'm using is actually more like a list of checkboxes [mat-selection-list](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists). I want to dynamically populate the list with data based on user input. I'm considering switching to regular checkboxes in a form to simplify the problem.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz to include checkboxes (after the options just to keep both). It is not 100% working yet ... but is that closer to what you are looking for?

Comment: OK. I have it working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-binding-deborahk Let me know if that is closer.

Comment: @DeborahK What I'm trying to do would be: each instance of the form has a checkbox labeled "Name: Foo Bar" and one labeled "Email: foo@bar.com". Every instance has a name checkbox and an email checkbox, but the foobar parts change based on the user's input. Basically the workflow is:  
  
The user inputs an unknown number of IDs - 
That number determines how many forms are generated - 
Each form has two checkboxes - 
The checkbox labels are as stated, where the foobar stuff is unique to each form instance and is retrieved from a database based on the IDs inputted by the user

Comment: @DeborahK I absolutely appreciate your help but I think it would be beneficial to move toward regular checkboxes as they're less complicated to implement using reactive forms.

Comment: The ones in my example *are* regular checkboxes? Consider doing your own stackblitz to better demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish.